# Android WebView and Widevine Persistent Licenses not supported?

Tags: android, android-webview, widevine, eme

I am working on an app that has an embedded WebView to play back DRM-protected content. While I can get the content to play correctly using Widevine, I cannot create an EME KeySystem that allows for persistent licenses (sessionTypes: ['persistent-license']).

Chrome on the Android devices do support persistent licenses under Chrome by checking: https://www.shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/support.html

```
    "com.widevine.alpha": {
      "persistentState": true
    }
```

However checking the same in the WebView shows persistence is *not* supported.

```
    "com.widevine.alpha": {
      "persistentState": false
    }
```

I'm assuming there is either a missing configuration or it is a missing feature with the WebView but documentation on the offline licenses is quite sparse.

Comment: Hi @Chris, we are in the same situation. Did you find any luck?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Chromium team this is currently not supported ([Bug #1217505](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1217505))